# Scroll box for specific container

Tags: scroll, scrollbar

How can i make scrolling content like on this page? I mean that scrolling gallery and text.
http://www.phuketatvsafariadventure.com/course/avt-safari/atv1hour.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set the div height and overflow scroll, like:

```
div {
   height: 150px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Take a look at: [css overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)